# java exceptions and scanner input

Tags: java, exception

i am trying to write an application in java that creates an object of a class and takes in user input to fill in the attributes of the object and can throw exceptions if the user enters invalid values. i put the conditions for exceptions in the setter methods in the class called Stuff.java and i created the exception classes. my problem is in the class that contains the main method, how do i code it to prompt the user to enter values for the attributes one after the other and it has to keep prompting the user for input untill the user has filled in values for the three attributes. here is my code below, the class that has the main method is not really giving me what i want. what changes do i have to make to it?

the Stuff class:

```
public class Stuff {
private int howMany;
private String name;
private boolean answer;

public void setHowMany(int howMany) throws InappropriateIntegerValue {
    if (howMany <= 0 || howMany >= 10000) {
        throw new InappropriateIntegerValue("in appropriate value");
    } else {
        this.howMany = howMany;
    }
}

public void setName(String name) throws IllegalStringValue {
    CharSequence car = "!@#%&*";
    if (name.length() < 6 || name.contains(car) != true
            || Character.isAlphabetic(name.charAt(0)) == false) {
        throw new IllegalStringValue("illegal string value");
    } else {
        this.name = name;
    }

}

public void setAnswer(String answer) throws InvalidBooleanValue {
    if (answer == "yes") {
        this.answer = true;
    } else if (answer == "no") {
        this.answer = false;
    } else {
        throw new InvalidBooleanValue("invalid respose");
    }
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Stuff [howMany=" + howMany + ", name=" + name + ", answer="
            + answer + "]";
}
```

}

the exception class for an illegal String value:

```
public class IllegalStringValue extends RuntimeException {

public IllegalStringValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public IllegalStringValue(String message) {
    super(message);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public IllegalStringValue(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public IllegalStringValue(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public IllegalStringValue(String message, Throwable cause,
        boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
    super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

the exception class for an illegal integer value

```
public class InappropriateIntegerValue extends RuntimeException {

public InappropriateIntegerValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InappropriateIntegerValue(String message) {
    super(message);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InappropriateIntegerValue(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InappropriateIntegerValue(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InappropriateIntegerValue(String message, Throwable cause,
        boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
    super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

the exception class for an illegal Boolean value:

```
public class InvalidBooleanValue extends RuntimeException {

public InvalidBooleanValue() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InvalidBooleanValue(String message) {
    super(message);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InvalidBooleanValue(Throwable cause) {
    super(cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InvalidBooleanValue(String message, Throwable cause) {
    super(message, cause);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

public InvalidBooleanValue(String message, Throwable cause,
        boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace) {
    super(message, cause, enableSuppression, writableStackTrace);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
```

}

the class with the main method, this is where I think I'm getting something wrong:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Stuff stf = new Stuff();
    Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
    int howMany;
    String name;
    String answer;

    System.out.println("enter number");
    howMany = userIn.nextInt();

    System.out.println("enter name");
    name = userIn.nextLine();

    System.out.println("enter answer");
    answer = userIn.nextLine();

    stf.setHowMany(howMany);
    stf.setAnswer(answer);
    stf.setName(name);

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem in your `nextInt()` function which is only read integer value and when you press enter it'll skip the `nextLine()`.

try `userIn.nextLine();` in your main method like this.

```
Scanner userIn = new Scanner(System.in);
int howMany;
String name;
String answer;

System.out.println("enter number");
howMany = userIn.nextInt();

System.out.println("enter name");
userIn.nextLine();
name = userIn.nextLine();

System.out.println("enter answer");
answer = userIn.nextLine();
```

Comment: Thanks alot @Omore. That's exacly what I needed

Comment: @kezie if this is right answer please marks this answer as right so that it'll helps future visitor. thanks